# socketio set socket id manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm useing socketio v0.9.16 I want to change socket id

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

      socket.id = 123;
      io.sockets.sockets[123].emit('test'); // emit doesn't work

});
```

any ideas? how can I do this

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the socket's id (in fact, this would probably break some things). You want to join a room. This should work (assuming you have a client-side listener for 'test'):

```
io.on('connection', function (socket){
  socket.join(123);
  io.sockets.to[123].emit('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SocketIO Docs says

> Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable, unique identifier Socket#id

So maybe you can do this instead.

```
var socket_list = [];

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket_list[""+123] = socket.id;
  io.sockets.sockets[socket_list[""+123]].emit('test');

});
```